# AWS S3 RoutingRule with wildcard condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a set of user folders with the same folder structure, but different content, stored in S3.

```
/user/userA/application/folder/structure/file.xml
/user/userB/application/folder/structure/file.xml
```

I would like to redirect the user to a fallback folder, (with fallback content) if the s3 folder structure don't exist for that user yet.

```
/user-fallback/application/folder/structure/file.xml
```

I've tried to add a wildcard parameter to my Redirection Rules, but S3 is reading `*` as a literal

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals>user/*/</KeyPrefixEquals>
            <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>user-fallback/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

So only urls starting with `/user/*/` are being correctly redirected to the `user-fallback` folder structure.

I have more than 20 users, so creating individual RoutingRules wouldn't work either (S3 has a routing rule limit)

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever make progress on this?

Comment: Also wondering if Amazon S3 routing rules allow any kind of wildcard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Routing Rules don't allow wildcards -- but couldn't you just put a custom redirect in for any 404 errors? See example#2 here: 
  [Example 2: Redirect requests for a deleted folder to a page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html)
Just change the condition to:

<HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404 </HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>

Would that work?

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals>user</KeyPrefixEquals>
            <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>user-fallback/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```